# spring cloud dataflow server on kubernetes error on dashboard loading

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-kubernetes

Trying to run the Spring Cloud Dataflow server on kubernetes .When i try to open the dashboard url (https://scdfserverurl/dashboard/#/apps )  in the browser its  partially loading and givingthe below error in the logs.The other components skipper is running fine and able access the url.

**Error stack trace**

2019-10-29 23:12:20.855+0000 [http-nio-9393-exec-9] ERROR o.s.c.d.s.c.RestControllerAdvice - Caught exception while handling a request
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [org.springframework.hateoas.Resources] and content type [text/html]
        at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:121)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:995)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:978)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:737)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:710)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:628)
        at org.springframework.hateoas.client.Traverson$TraversalBuilder.toObject(Traverson.java:344)
        at org.springframework.cloud.skipper.client.DefaultSkipperClient.listDeployers(DefaultSkipperClient.java:335)
        at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.stream.SkipperStreamDeployer.platformList(SkipperStreamDeployer.java:610)
        at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.DefaultStreamService.platformList(DefaultStreamService.java:339)
        at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.DefaultStreamService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$89697014.invoke()
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
        at  org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
        at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.DefaultStreamService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a40fcfc9.platformList()
        at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.controller.StreamDeploymentController.platformList(StreamDeploymentController.java:122)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.ForwardedHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ForwardedHeaderFilter.java:157)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:679)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

**Kubernetes config YML**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: scdf-server-network-policy
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: scdf-server
  ingress:
    - from:
        - namespaceSelector:
            matchLabels:
              gkp_namespace: ingress-nginx
  egress:
    - {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: poc-pull-secret
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: ewogICJhdXRocyI6IHsKI
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson      
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: scdf-server
  labels:
    app: scdf-server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: scdf-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: scdf-server
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/psp: nonroot
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: scdf-server
          image: <quay_url>/scdf-server:0.0.9-scdf
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9393
              protocol: TCP
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: "4"
              memory: 2Gi
            requests:
              cpu: 25m
              memory: 1Gi
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 99 
          env:
            - name: SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_CLIENT_SERVER_URI
              value: "<skipper_server_url>/api"
            - name: SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_FEATURES_SKIPPER_ENABLED
              value: "true"             
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: poc-pull-secret
      serviceAccount: spark
      serviceAccountName: spark
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: scdf-server
  labels:
    app: scdf-server
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 9393
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    app: scdf-server
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: scdf-server
  annotations:    
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow.http: false
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "<app_url>"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: scdf-server
              servicePort: 80
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - "<app_url>"
```

**POM.XML for the Dataflow Server**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>pocgroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>scdf-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Spring Cloud Data Flow :: Server</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <description>Spring Cloud Dataflow Server</description>

    <!-- Spring Boot Dependency -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dataflow-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <revision>0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</revision>
        <jacoco.skip.instrument>true</jacoco.skip.instrument>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.2</version>
                <classifier>runtime</classifier>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.8</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-dataflow-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
            <classifier>runtime</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sybase.jconnect</groupId>
            <artifactId>jconn4</artifactId>
            <version>7.07-27307</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <jacoco-agent.destfile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                        <version>2.21.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-instrument</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>instrument</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>${jacoco.skip.instrument}</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-restore-instrumented-classes</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>${jacoco.skip.instrument}</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>${jacoco.skip.instrument}</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnNoGitDirectory>false</failOnNoGitDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-it-test-source</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                            <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/it/java</source>
                            </sources>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/it/resources</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>checkstyle-validation</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>

        <profile>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>run-integration-tests</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Hi, What version of SCDF is this? Looks like the Skipper client is missing the necessary Http Message Converters. The SkipperClient should have the HttpMessageConverters added via SCDF configuration.

Comment: <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
        <spring-cloud-skipper.version>2.0.3.RELEASE</spring-cloud-skipper.version>

Comment: just noticed the issue is due to skipper server  return http urls and  dataflow server getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to the https - http redirection due to which dataflow server wasnt able to hit  the skipper/deployer rest end point .Below link has the details 
 [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58683372/skipper-https-rest-end-point-requests-returning-http-urls)